# Regularize continuous functions with bounded variation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Is it true that :

$\forall f,g \in C([0,1],\mathbb R), \exists h \in C([0,1],[0,1])$ $f,g,h$ strictly increasing and $h([0,1])=[0,1]$ with $(f \circ h, g\circ h) \in C^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb R)^2$?

Comment: It was kind of you to add the homeomorphism assumption about $h$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is NO:

Let $\,f:[0;1]\to[0;1]\,$ be the identity function. Let $\,g:[0;1]\to[0;1]\,$ be such that the set of $\,D\subseteq[0;1]\,$ of points $\,x\in[0;1]\,$ for which derivative of $\,g\,$ doesn't exist is dense.

Then, if $\,f\circ h\,$ is smooth then $\,h\,$ is smooth.

But then $\,g\circ h\,$ cannot be smooth. Otherwise, the derivative of $\,h\,$ at every $\,y\in h^{-1}(D)\,$ would be $0,\,$ and $\,h^{-1}(D)\,$ would be dense ($\,h\,$ is really assumed to be a homeomorphism), hence $\,h\,$ would be constant. A contradiction.   ***Great!***

> ***For the sake of mine and everybody's peace of mind let me add the ultimate detail:***

Assume that $\,g\circ h\,$ is smooth, and that the derivative of smooth  $h$ at point $\,h^{-1}(x)$ is not $0\,$ for a certain point $x$. Then, $g$ is differentiable at $x$.

**Indeed**,  the derivative of $\,g\,$ at $\,x\,$ is the derivative at $x$ of $\,g\,=\,(g\circ h)\circ h^{-1}.\,$

Happy New Year!

Comment: why the derivative of $h$ at every $y\in h^{-1}(D)$ would be $0$ ?

Comment: For instance, if $h$ were constant then $\,g\circ h\,$ would be smooth.

Comment: it does not seem to me that you are answering my question.

Comment: @Dattier, I've misread your question (have imagined a question which could have been "natural" to ask). You already know at the stage of the proof that $h$ is smooth. Thus at the critical points that derivate (would exist and)  being **different** from zero would not compose with $g$ to a smooth function.

Comment: I may add a small but truly detailed note at the end of the Answer if you still would like me to do so.